# deploy terraform files that are stored locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I wish to deploy a infrastructure that is written as a terraform module. This module is as follows:

```
module "my-module" {
  count = var.env == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  source = "s3::https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-directory/"

  env = var.env
  deployment = var.deployment
}
```

Right now this is in a `my-module.tf file`, and I am deploying it by running the usual `terraform init`, `plan` and `apply` commands (and passing in the relevant variables).

However, for my specific requirements, I wish to be able to deploy this only by running `terraform init`, `plan` and `apply` commands (and passing in the relevant variables), and not having to store the module in a file on my own machine. I would rather have the module file be stored remotely (e.g. s3 bucket) so other teams/users do not need to have the file on their own machine. Is there any way this terraform could be deployed in such a way that the module file can be stored remotely, and could for example be passed as an option when running terraform `plan` and `apply` commands?

Comment: doing it the usual way by deploying ```my-module.tf``` works, but I am seeking a solution where I do not need to store my-module.tf locally on my own machine, and I would instead like it to be stored remotely.

Answer (score 0):

> could for example be passed as an option when running terraform plan and apply commands?

It's not possible. As explained in [TF docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/syntax#source), `source` must be a **literal string**. Which means it can't be any dynamic variable.

You would have to develop your own wrapper around TF, which would do simple find-and-replace `source` place-holders with actual correct values before you use `terraform`.

Comment: I'm happy to pass things as literal strings, I only ever want to deploy one specific module/piece of infrastructure, my only issue is that I do not want to have the terraform file itself on the user's own machine

Comment: @SaboBoz `source` must be hard-coded. This is what it means to be a literal string.

Comment: Yes I'm happy to hardcode that - the source I wish to use will never change

Comment: @SaboBoz So then what exactly do you want to "passed as an option"?

Comment: if we stored the ```my-module.tf``` file in s3 for example, then would there be something like an option to pass the url of this file (in s3) to the ```terraform apply``` command, so that the ```terraform apply``` command uses the ```my-module.tf``` file in s3, rather than a local file?

Comment: @SaboBoz "pass the url of this file" and do what with it? Use as a `source` argument in a module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249948/discussion-between-sabo-boz-and-marcin).